# How to get Android Album with audio files to HTML?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am trying to list a tab to filter by Album. I have managed to display all audio files at another tab "All".

I did manage to show Album name by using MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM. If an album have 5 songs, it will populate 5 album names.

How can I group them together and clickable as a "folder" and show inside audio items?

My code at Android Studio to get the Album name:

```
public ArrayList<AudioModel> getAllAudioFromDevice (Context context){
        final ArrayList<AudioModel> tempAudioList = new ArrayList<>();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION,
        };

        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                AudioModel audioModel = new AudioModel();
                String path = c.getString(0); // Retrieve path.
                String name = c.getString(1); // Retrieve name.
                String album = c.getString(2); // Retrieve album name.
                String artist = c.getString(3); // Retrieve artist name.
                String duration = c.getString(4); // Retrieve duration.

                audioModel.setaName(name);
                audioModel.setaAlbum(album);
                audioModel.setaArtist(artist);
                audioModel.setaPath(path);
                audioModel.setaDuration(duration);

                tempAudioList.add(audioModel);

            }
            c.close();
        }

        return tempAudioList;

    }
```

My JavascriptInterface code at Android Studio:

```
@JavascriptInterface
        public String getmp3album(){
            ArrayList<AudioModel> allMp3 = getAudioAlbumFromDevice(this.activity);
            List<AudioModel> listStrings = new ArrayList<>(allMp3);

            String tempAlbum= "";

            for (int i = 0; i < listStrings.size(); i++) {

                String AudioAlbum = listStrings.get(i).aAlbum;

                    tempAlbum += AudioAlbum + ",";

            }

            return tempAlbum;
        }
```

My HTML index.html side code:

```
<div id="albumwrap">
                <ul id="albumlist"></ul>
            </div>
```

My Javascript code at index.html:

```
function showAlbumList(){

    var stringAlbum = window.AndroidFunction.getmp3album();
    var arrayAlbum = stringAlbum.split(",");


    var select = document.getElementById('albumlist');        

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayAlbum.length; i++) {

        var li = document.createElement("li");             
        li.setAttribute('class', 'plItem');

        var link = document.createElement("a");            
        link.setAttribute('class', 'plTitle');
        link.setAttribute('href', arrayAlbum[i]);           
        li.appendChild(link);                               
        var text = document.createTextNode(arrayAlbum[i]);
        link.appendChild(text);                            

        select.insertBefore(li, select.childNodes[i]);
    }
}
window.onLoad = showAlbumList();
```

Now showing: 
Album1
Album1
Album1
Album2
Album2

Expected:
+Album1
  -song1
  -song2
  -song3
+Album2
  -song1
  -song2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a webview, then what you can do is replace it with Rich text view: https://github.com/square1-io/rich-text-android

Then using the above library, and set "setOnSpanClickedObserver" to get the desired output